# requiring assets from gem doe not work anymore in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

I have a Rails 4.1(.10) app that I'm trying to upgrade to Rails 4.2(.1) but I have an hard time doing so.

The issue is related to how assets are loaded from a gem I use to share assets among multiple apps.

In my gem I have the following code

```
# /assets_gem/app/assets/javascript/my_js.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require turbolinks
//= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert
//= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip
//= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover
```

and in assets_gem/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap I have the 3 js files.

In my Rails app I have the following code

```
# idx/app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require my_js
//= require_tree ./application
```

Everything works fine in Rails 4.1.10 and Sprockets 2.12.3 but when I upgrade to Rails 4.2.1 and Sprockets 3.0.1 I get the error below

> Sprockets::FileNotFound at / couldn't find file
>   '../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert' with
>   type 'application/javascript'

Should I require my vendor assets in a different way under Sprockets 3+?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vendor/assets/javascripts` is already included in default search path and thus all you need is `require bootstrap/bootstrap-alert` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the path in your application.rb

config.assets << Rails.root.join('vendor','assets', 'my_components')